# Installing helm on minikube return an error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have followed the steps as described in [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/webinar-series-kubernetes-package-management-with-helm-and-ci-cd-with-jenkins-x) link.

When i am on section of `helm install` (Step 2), and trying to run:

```
helm install --name web ./demo
```

I am getting the following error:

> Get https://10.96.0.1:443/version?timeout=32s: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout

Expected Result: It should install and deploy the chart.

Comment: It might not be an issue with helm itself, in a typical Kubernetes cluster, the API serves on port 443. And it would seem that you cannot connect to it, did you customize the port? or maybe it's not running correctly

Answer (score 0):

This issue relates to your kubernetes configuration and not to your helm.
Assume you are also not able see outputs from other helm commands like `helm list` , etc.

Lots of people have this issue because of not properly configured CNI(typically this is calico). And sometimes this happens because of your [kubeconfig](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/) absence.

Solutions are:

- migrate from [calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.0/getting-started/kubernetes/) to [flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel-cni)
- Change the `--pod-network-cidr` for calico from `192.168.0.0/16 to 172.16.0.0/16` when using kubeadm to init cluster, like `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=172.16.0.0`

More related info you han find on [similar github helm issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3347)

Simple single-machine example:

1) `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=172.16.0.0/16`

2) `kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-`

3) `kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.8/manifests/calico.yaml`

```
configmap/calico-config created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/felixconfigurations.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/ipamblocks.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/blockaffinities.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/ipamhandles.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/ipamconfigs.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/bgppeers.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/bgpconfigurations.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/ippools.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/hostendpoints.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/clusterinformations.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/globalnetworkpolicies.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/globalnetworksets.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/networkpolicies.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/networksets.crd.projectcalico.org created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/calico-kube-controllers created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/calico-kube-controllers created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/calico-node created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/calico-node created
daemonset.apps/calico-node created
serviceaccount/calico-node created
deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers created
serviceaccount/calico-kube-controllers created
```

4)install helm

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get | bash
kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
helm init --service-account tiller
```

5)create and install chart

```
$ helm create demo
Creating demo
$ helm install --name web ./demo
NAME:   web
LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Jul 16 10:44:15 2019
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1/Deployment
NAME      READY  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  AGE
web-demo  0/1    1           0          0s

==> v1/Pod(related)
NAME                       READY  STATUS             RESTARTS  AGE
web-demo-6986c66d7d-vctql  0/1    ContainerCreating  0         0s

==> v1/Service
NAME      TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)  AGE
web-demo  ClusterIP  10.106.140.176  <none>       80/TCP   0s


NOTES:
1. Get the application URL by running these commands:
  export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=demo,app.kubernetes.io/instance=web" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
  echo "Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080 to use your application"
  kubectl port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:80
```

6)result

```
$ kubectl get all
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/web-demo-6986c66d7d-vctql   1/1     Running   0          75s


NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP   11m
service/web-demo     ClusterIP   10.106.140.176   <none>        80/TCP    75s


NAME                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/web-demo   1/1     1            1           75s

NAME                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/web-demo-6986c66d7d   1         1         1       75s
```

You can find more info in how to configure helm and kubernetes itself in [Get Started With Kubernetes Using Minikube](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/get-started-kubernetes/)  article